# Object caching multiple queries with same where clause

Tags: django, django-models

Just wondering if Django 2.2 ORM caches the returned QuerySets in this code, or are the queries executed on the DB for each call?  Is there a way to tell Django to "re-use" the QuerySets to lesson impact on DB.

I'm building this application which retrieves several values and objects for different reasons, but the underlying query is the same in each case .

```py
hrs = Sale.objects.filter(createdate = dte).aggregate(sum=Sum('duration'))['sum'] / 60

stf = Sale.objects.filter(createdate = dte).values_list('idsalestaff', flat=True).distinct().count()

csh = Sale.objects.filter(createdate = dte).aggregate(sum=Sum('cash'))['sum']

crd = Sale.objects.filter(createdate = dte).aggregate(sum=Sum('card'))['sum']
```

Answer (score 0):

All query sets are lazy in **Django**, so none of them are actually executed until you fetch the data from the query set to your application (with a `for` loop, for example).

You can make a query and apply more queries over it (`hrs.filter(createdate=dte)`), but it is still lazy, so you haven't hit the database yet.

You can force the execution of the query by [one of these methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated).